# What is this Simulator disk image in Disk Utility?

Tags: disk-utility

When I run Disk Utility (on Monterey), I see listed among my disks:

> **Disk Images**
>
> iOS 16.0 Simulator

Why? What is a simulator disk image and why is it "open"?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, this has something to do with how Xcode makes older simulator SDKs available. The current SDK is iOS 16.2, but I also had downloaded iOS 16.0 (because 16.2 has introduced some bugs that I wanted to confirm by comparison with 16.0). This disk image is how the system presents the downloaded `simruntime` file to Xcode, it appears.

Comment: Interesting. Some observations: Older SDKs (I tried it with iOS 14.5) are not in a disk image. "hdiutil info" shows both the path to the disk image (/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Images/SomeUUID.dmg) and the mount point (/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_20A360). The image is mounted when Xcode is started but not unmounted when Xcode is quit, it stays mounted until the user logs off.